# Loop inside a Raw Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 Models:

```
  Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

  Image(models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_images',   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

In Django to do a reverse FK query(from Product to Image) a prefetch_related. is usually use.

Because I have a more complex query with multiple conditions and a Lateral Join in a case I preferred to do a RAW Queryset.

The most simplistic case:

```
SELECT *, i.image, FROM item AS t
 INNER JOIN image AS i on t.id = i.item_id
```

Taking in consideration, that and item can have one or multiple images how can I retrieve the images for each item.

I use raw because I want to get only the first 3 images per each product(and specific file type)

In `prefetch case`, I can loop over `item.item_images` , but in this case ?

Comment: try with Item.item_images.all() maybe?

Comment: And use select_related instead of prefetch_related https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Your question does not specify the use case in details. Also, it's a best practice of django to only use raw sql when everything else fails to optimize your querying. In your case @Bast solution would be ok. But you should use Image.objects.filter(item_id=item_id_you_need).select_related("item") since that seems to conform to the sql query more.

Comment: @Bast select_related works if I need images(where is the FK) to get product not viceversa